# How to use generate string using '=>' operator in php

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to set string in foreach loop using =>. Problem is, if I use => operator then string create correctly and generate error... please help me... my sample code is

```
$field = array();
    $cond = array();
    foreach ($fields as $val) {
        $field[] = $model.'.'.$val;
        $cond[] = $model.'.'.$val.' '.'LIKE '.=>."%".$value."%";
    }
```

I have generate string like

```
'or'=>array('ErpProduct.ProductCode LIKE'=>"%".$value."%",'ErpProduct.ProductName LIKE'=>"%".$value."%"),
```

Comment: Enclose it in the quote...? Why do you need `=>` there in the first place?

Comment: for cakephp query standard

Answer (score 2):

There is no `=>` operator in php, `=>` is used in the array literal.

What you should do is just setting it as array index like below:

```
foreach ($fields as $val) {
   $field[] = $model.'.'.$val;
   $cond[$model.'.'.$val.' '.'LIKE '] =　"%".$value."%";
}
```

Comment: If I setting it as array index then it gives
Array
(
    [ErpProduct.ProductCode LIKE ] => %Atish%
    [ErpProduct.ProductName LIKE ] => %Atish%
)
which is genearte error in cakephp query.